# Expose moderator-only and required tags in SEDE

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, data-explorer, moderator-tags

The API has two methods to get a list of required tags (the gray ones) and moderator-only tags (the red ones):

- [required tags](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/required-tags)
- [moderator only tags](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/moderator-only-tags)

That means there must be an enumeration (or two booleans) in the database to distinguish them from regular tags. Can that column/those columns please be added to the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I'll get this in place for a SEDE extract next week. We're on a code/build freeze for the holiday, so I can't deploy any changes to the underlying views until next week.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was deployed last week and the extract process yesterday grabbed the new columns.

There are two new bit columns on the Tags table:

- IsModeratorOnly
- IsRequired